# In go 1.20.1 , is fmt.Printf("Processes took #{elapsed}") wrong?

Tags: go, goland

I am learning

[image]

related https://github.com/donhuvy/Up-and-Running-with-Concurrency-in-Go-Golang-/blob/main/4-First_Goroutine/NotUsingGoroutines.go#L20

In go 1.20.1, Is my program wrong

File `main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    doSomething()
    doSomethingElse()

    fmt.Println("\n\nI guess I'm done")
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("Processes took #{elapsed}")
}

func doSomething() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Println("\nI've done something")
}

func doSomethingElse() {
    fmt.Println("do abc esle")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is **incorrect** syntax for `fmt` format strings:

```golang
fmt.Printf("Processes took #{elapsed}")
```

The **correct** version would look like:

```golang
fmt.Printf("Processes took %s", elapsed)
```

This is regardless of which Go version you are using. The reason why you may have seen the first version is that GoLand will display the second version as if it were the first. The visual cue for this is that the format string is in grey, rather than the typical green for string literals, and also highlighted. That is the visual formatting that GoLand uses to indicate that what you're seeing is not the actual code, but a translated version that is supposed to be more readable.

The first version is not and was never valid Go code. It is just a shorthand that GoLand *displays* automatically.